# Extract frame timecodes from DV AVI

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I have some ancient DV AVI files (Type 1) from my camcorder.

I would like to export the `timecode` of each frame to a seperate file. [Here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html#Timecode) I read that `ffprobe` supports timecode extraction, but it is confusing since it mentions `-show_format`. As far as I know, DV AVI format encodes timecodes *per frame*.

Anyway here is what I get for `ffprobe -show_format testcc.avi`:

```
ffprobe version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200621
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[avi @ 0000025da5e55bc0] Switching to NI mode, due to poor interleaving
Input #0, avi, from 'testcc.avi':
  Duration: 00:06:16.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 28882 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: dvvideo, yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 25000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
[FORMAT]
filename=testcc.avi
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=avi
format_long_name=AVI (Audio Video Interleaved)
start_time=0.000000
duration=376.680000
size=1359912960
bit_rate=28882084
probe_score=100
[/FORMAT]
```

And for `ffprobe -show_frames testcc.avi`:

```
...
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=0
key_frame=1
pkt_pts=0
pkt_pts_time=0.000000
pkt_dts=0
pkt_dts_time=0.000000
best_effort_timestamp=0
best_effort_timestamp_time=0.000000
pkt_duration=1
pkt_duration_time=0.040000
pkt_pos=65032
pkt_size=144000
width=720
height=576
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=16:15
pict_type=I
coded_picture_number=0
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=1
top_field_first=1
repeat_pict=0
color_range=unknown
color_space=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
chroma_location=topleft
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
...
```

And for `ffprobe -show_streams testcc.avi`:

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=dvvideo
codec_long_name=DV (Digital Video)
profile=unknown
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/25
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=720
height=576
coded_width=720
coded_height=576
closed_captions=0
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=16:15
display_aspect_ratio=4:3
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=-99
color_range=unknown
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=topleft
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=25/1
avg_frame_rate=25/1
time_base=1/25
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=25000000
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=pcm_s16le
codec_long_name=PCM signed 16-bit little-endian
profile=unknown
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=s16
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=16
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/30000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=1536000
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
[/STREAM]
```

I don't see any `timecode`. In Movie Maker (yes I know... it's on an old VM) I do see all the correct `timecodes` per frame. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `ffprobe -show_streams testcc.avi` show?

Comment: @Gyan, the reason you are asking is?

Comment: Typically, the timecode is a starting frame timecode stored in the stream's metadata.

Comment: @Gyan, sure I added it, but I don't understand why `show_treams` and `show_format` are relevant since DV AVI stores full timecodes per frame.